# NullPointerException error in POM code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium, android-automation

Setup Class

```
public class Setup {

    private static AndroidDriver driver = initializeAppiumServer();

    public static AndroidDriver initializeAppiumServer() {

        if (driver == null || driver.toString().contains("(null)")) {

            DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "HXT7Nwewewe9");
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "android");
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.abc.abc");
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity",
                    "com.abc.abc.ui.activity.SplashActivity");
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);

            try {
                driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.2.0.3:7725/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Initializing Appium Server");
            return driver;
        } else {
            return driver;
        }
    }

}
```

Test class

```
public class LoginTest {

    private LoginPage loginpage;
    private DashboardPage dashboardPage;

    public LoginTest() {

        loginpage = new LoginPage();
        dashboardPage = new DashboardPage();

    }

    @Given("^Launch app$")
    public void Launchapp() {
        loginpage.launchapp();

    }

@Then("^Get logged in$")
public void Getloggedin() {
    loginpage.Login();
    dashboardPage.navigate(); //calling from Dashboard page


}
```

LoginPage Class

```
public class LoginPage{

    private AndroidDriver driver;

    public void launchapp() {
        driver = new Setup().initializeAppiumServer();
    }

     public void Login() {

    driver.findElement(Usernametxt).sendKeys("ABC");
    driver.findElement(Passwordtxt).sendKeys("ABC")
    driver.findElement(Loginbtn).click();

}
```

DashboardPage Class

```
    public class DashboardPage {

        private AndroidDriver driver;

        // Where fails
        public void navigate() {
            By settingsbtn = By.id("Button");

            driver.findElement(settingsbtn).click();

        }


        }
```

When I run I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException for DashboardPage navigate()function, But all works fine if i add the function to the login page. Is this something to do with the driver? How to solve this?

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace of the NPE?

Answer (score 1):

**1. you are not passing any driver instance to the Dashboard DashboardPage**

**2. You are trying to access local variable 'driver' which is not initialized yet**

**Solution:**

**Add :**

```
 public void launchapp() {
        driver = new Setup().initializeAppiumServer();
    }
```

**Or pass the already initialized driver to the dashboard:**

in your dashboard class also or pass the driver object to dashboard class before trying to find element.

**Correct approach**

**Test Class:**:

```
public class LoginTest {

    private LoginPage loginpage;
    private DashboardPage dashboardPage;
    private AndroidDriver driver;

    public LoginTest() {
        driver= Setup().initializeAppiumServer()
        loginpage = new LoginPage(driver);
        dashboardPage = new DashboardPage(driver);

    }

    @Given("^Launch app$")
    public void Launchapp() {
        loginpage.launchapp();

    }

@Then("^Get logged in$")
public void Getloggedin() {
    loginpage.Login();
    dashboardPage.navigate(); //calling from Dashboard page


}
```

**Login Class**

```
public class LoginPage{

    private AndroidDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(driverInst) {
        driver = driverInst;
    }
public void launchapp() {
    driver.launchApp();
}

     public void Login() {

    driver.findElement(Usernametxt).sendKeys("ABC");
    driver.findElement(Passwordtxt).sendKeys("ABC")
    driver.findElement(Loginbtn).click();

}
```

**Dashboard class:**

```
  public class DashboardPage {



    private AndroidDriver driver;

    public DashboardPage(driverInst) {
        driver = driverInst;
    }

            // Where fails
    public void navigate() {
          By settingsbtn = By.id("Button");
          driver.findElement(settingsbtn).click();

      }

            }
```